# How can I shut down a Derby connection that has been made by another program?

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection, derby, sqlexception

I have written a test program that makes a Derby connection and creates the necessary tables if they do not exist. But once I run the programme I can't rerun it again because the exception I have brought. I think that I should add a finilize method to the current singletone class and close the connection there. Is it the solution?

But anyway I consider the possiblity of the program crash and exiting from the program in an abnormal manner. In that case how can I force to close the other instances of the connection to the database safely and make my own connection?

```
public class DBTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DBConnection.getInstance();
    }
}


public class DBConnection {
    private static DBConnection ourInstance = new DBConnection();

    private Connection connection;

    public static DBConnection getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private DBConnection() {

        String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
        String dbName="C:/Users/Puk/IdeaProjects/DerbyTest/database/Ablauf";
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:derby:" + dbName + ";create=true";
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        createTables();
    }

    private void createTables(){
        Statement s;
        try {
            s = connection.createStatement();
            s.execute("CREATE TABLE category ( id  SMALLINT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY \n" +
                    "\t(START WITH 0, INCREMENT BY 1), title  VARCHAR(100))");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'C:/Users/Puk/IdeaProjects/DerbyTest/database/Ablauf' with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1830e4a7, see the next exception for details.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.seeNextException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection40.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver20.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:243)
    at model.DBConnection.<init>(DBConnection.java:31)
    at model.DBConnection.<clinit>(DBConnection.java:12)
    at test.DBTest.main(DBTest.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'C:/Users/Puk/IdeaProjects/DerbyTest/database/Ablauf' with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1830e4a7, see the next exception for details.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database C:\Users\Puk\IdeaProjects\DerbyTest\database\Ablauf.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database C:\Users\Puk\IdeaProjects\DerbyTest\database\Ablauf.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.privGetJBMSLockOnDB(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.getJBMSLockOnDB(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.RawStore.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootStore(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startProviderService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.findProviderAndStartService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    ... 17 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at test.DBTest.main(DBTest.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at model.DBConnection.createTables(DBConnection.java:41)
    at model.DBConnection.<init>(DBConnection.java:35)
    at model.DBConnection.<clinit>(DBConnection.java:12)
    ... 6 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: There will be a dead process somewhere in the background, kill it via task manager.  It will be named java or javaw, you may want to close your IDE first, to avoid killing it inadvertently.  That being said, you should ***really*** improve your error handling, as right now you don't do anything with errors except write them on screen, and then continue just to see the next line crash and burn.

Comment: @fvu I think that If I kill java, I would have killed all java programs including my IDEs. The program is for test and up to an hour ago I had never written a program using Derby, so thanks for error handling comment but they must be replaced with JOptionPane/System.exit(0) in the final code. The more important thing is when the user uses the program. S/he doesn't know that must kill that process in the task manager and I must do it for him/her.

Comment: no, every java process has its separate java or javaw process loaded.  And you should make your program so that it handles errors properly and detaches properly from the db, of course I'm not suggesting your users should do that.  The fact that it happened now is very probably directly linked with the nonexistent error handling and recovery, so you should solve that issue.  If you want some reading stuff, the [official tutorial on JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) is quite good.

Comment: Thanks for the doc link. Honestly that's a must-read that I have never done. But I'm still preoccupied for the case that the program crashes. For that I defined a dummy server_socket to prevent another instance of the program if one is already running and it looks impossible to be able to detect the previous process of the program programmatically and kill it.

Comment: In real life a crashed program will disappear from memory in the great majority of cases, processes getting stuck during debugging or running under an IDE is a lot more common.  But really believ me, prevention is the name of the game, you should really build in decent error handling and recovery.  That should get rid of 99.99% of problems you will encounter.

Comment: You're right! If I exit the program on fatal errors it doesn't remain in memory. Unfortunately IntelliJ Idea doesn't show the the other running programs in its console so I should shut down them from the task manager.(I'm comming to the idea that netbeans was faster and better) I think you pointed the answer correctly! Thanks!

Comment: As a Netbeans user I can confirm that sporadically Netbeans loses track of programs under development as well - it's just one of these small annoyances related to development, and killing them via taskmanager is not a big deal, I only once whacked my IDE instead of the program being tested, you'll quickly get the hang of it!  Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot boot a db from multiple jvms at the same time. This is explained in the docs [Derby Dev Guide](https://builds.apache.org/job/Derby-docs/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/out/devguide/cdevdvlp20458.html)

HTH

D